# Evitar que se muestre el día anterior al obtener fecha de un input

Tags: javascript, date

Tengo que usar Javascript, es un `<input type="date">` y a la hora de escoger cualquier fecha y mandarla a imprimir, me imprime la de un día anterior. Vivo en CDMX y no sé si la zona horaria esta mal:

```js
function funcionfecha(){
  var Fecha =  new Date(document.getElementById("fecha").value);
  window.alert(Fecha);
}
```

```html
<input type="date" id="fecha" onChange="funcionfecha( this.value )">
```

Por ejemplo escogí la fecha de hoy Viernes 6 de Septiembre del 2019 y me sale esto:

```
Tue Sep 05 2019 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (hora de verano central).
```

La fecha es pasada.

Comment: Agregarías por favor el resto de tu código donde esta el llamado a la librería datepicker?

Comment: <input type="date" id="fecha" onChange="funcionfecha( this.value )"> eso es lo que tengo para el campo date, y la funcionfecha es lo que tengo arriba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las Fechas en Javascript incluyen el huso horario, si te fijas, al final pone "19:00:00 GMT-0500", lo que significa que tu huso horario está cinco horas por delante del uso horario UTC, es decir, que si le sumas 5 horas a Sep 05 2019 19:00:00, obtendrás la fecha en UTC Sep 06 2019 00:00:00, si lo que quieres es tarbajar con fechas en UTC puedes usar las funciones que provee Javascript por defecto:

```
Fecha.toUTCString() <- esto te imprimirá Sat, 06 Sep 2019 00:00:00 GMT
Fecha.getUTCDay()
Fecha.getUTCMonth()
etc ...
```

O para más funcionalidad utiliza la biblioteca [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), que tiene muchísimas utilidades a la hora de trabajar con fechas

Comment: Ya lo puse así, pero aun me sigue saliendo un día atrás
var Fecha =  new Date(document.getElementById("fecha").value);
Fecha.toUTCString();
Fecha.getUTCDay();
 Fecha.getUTCMonth();
 Fecha.getUTCDate();
window.alert(Fecha);

Comment: Esas funciones son algunos ejemplos de funciones que puedes usar para trabajar con fechas en formato UTC, si lo único que quieres es mostrarla en un alert simplemente usa window.alert(Fecha.toUTCString());

Answer (score 1):

Para mostrar fechas obtenidas de un input date debes convertirlas a la zona horaria estándar UTC, por ejemplo para obtener la cadena de la fecha puedes emplear `toUTCString()`:

```js
function funcionfecha(){
  var Fecha =  new Date(document.getElementById("fecha").value);
  console.log(Fecha.toUTCString());
  console.log(`${Fecha.getUTCDate()}/${Fecha.getUTCMonth()+1}/${Fecha.getUTCFullYear()}`);
}
```

```html
<input type="date" id="fecha" onChange="funcionfecha()">
```

Luego para imprimir las fechas puedes usar las respectivas funciones y usar una plantilla de cadenas para mostrarlas (ademas de sumarle 1 al mes ya que en UTC se muestra del 0 - 11).

Espero te sirva, saludos.